# Hierarchical clustering and optimal amount of clusters

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to use hierarchical clusterings to order sites with similar fish densities, but i'm having trouble with my hierarchical clustering and finding the optimal number of clusters. The dataset I'm working with has 15 districts with about 24 fish species and 38 sites (depending on the district).

So I am having trouble with the code for the hclust and how to find the optimal amount of clusters.

For this, I have tried to automate finding the optimal number of clusters for all my districts and drawing hclust.
My most recent updated code (not functioning, for some reason that's beyond me at the moment) is this:

```
for (district in list_of_all_districts) {
  n = n + 1 
  print(paste("Processing", district ), n)
    
  
  district_data <- opti_cluster[opti_cluster$Huvudavrinningsområde == district , ]
  
  district_data_filtered <- district_data %>% 
    select(-Huvudavrinningsområde, -Lokal, -ykoorvdr, -xkoorvdr)
  
  district_data_filtered <- district_data_filtered[, colSums(district_data_filtered[, 1:ncol(district_data_filtered)]) != 0]
  
  
  if (ncol(district_data_filtered) > 0) {
    
    if (ncol(district_data_filtered) >= 2) {

    # Calculate the dissimilarity matrix
    dissimilarity_matrix <- dist(district_data_filtered)
    
    # Initialize variables to store results
    wss <- vector()
    
    # k_values <- 4:20  # Range of cluster numbers to consider
    #actually expecting a number close to 4-6 to be optimal amount of clusters
    
    for (k_value in 4:20) {
      # Perform hierarchical clustering with k clusters
      hclust_model <- hclust(dissimilarity_matrix)
      cutree_result <- cutree(hclust_model, k = k_value)
      
      # Calculate within-cluster variance
      wss[k_value] <- sum((dissimilarity_matrix[lower.tri(dissimilarity_matrix)] -
                       mean(dissimilarity_matrix))^2)
      
    }
    
    
    # Identify the "elbow" point (optimal number of clusters)
    diff_wss <- diff(wss)
    elbow_point <- k_values[which(diff_wss == max(diff_wss)) + 1]

    plot(x = hclust_model)
    
    fviz_dend(x = res_H, cex = 0.7, lwd = 0.7, k = elbow_point, 
              rect = T,
              rect_fill = T)
    
    
    cat("Optimal Number of Clusters (Elbow Method) in", district, ":", print(elbow_point), "\n")
    } else {
      cat("No numeric columns remaining after filtering for", district, "\n")
    }
  } else {
    # Handle the case where all columns sum to 0
    cat("No data remaining after filtering for", Avrinningsområde, "\n")
  }
}
```

I have also tried visualizing the Explained variance for one of the districts to locate the elbow point manually but it didn't show a clear elbow [Elbow District 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb9S0.png).

Example of how my data looks:

| Site | Perch | Trout |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 8.5 |
| B | 0 | 0.5 |
| C | 0 | 186.8 |
| D | 17.9 | 48.9 |
| E | 1.01 | 9.9 |